# Program will build on Netbeans 11.2 but the jar file wont do what it suppose to do

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I am writing a program for sorta fun for my work its mainly for me to use but the problem is that it will run in the netbeans editor but if i build the project it will not run when the .jar is used

```
public class finalprogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                            String row;

        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("target\\book1.csv"));//reads the csv

        while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = row.split(",");//saves the data from each row seperated by a comma
            System.out.println(data[0]);
            File myFile = new File("target\\phones\\" + data[0] + ".cfg");//creates file location with the data recieved from the file read
            writer(myFile, data);
            if (myFile.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }
        }

        csvReader.close();
    } 

        static private void writer(File myFile, String[] data) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myFile);
        writer.write("#!version:1.0.0.1 \n");
        writer.write("## the file header \"#!version:1.0.0.1\" can not be edited or deleted. ##\n");

        writer.write("\naccount.1.auth_name = " + data[1]);
        writer.write("\naccount.1.display_name = " + data[2]);
        writer.write("\naccount.1.enable = 1");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.label = " + data[3]);
        writer.write("\naccount.1.password = " + data[4]);
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.address = " + data[5]);
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.expires = ");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.failback_mode = 0");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.failback_timeout = ");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.port = 0");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.register_on_enable = 0");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.sip_server.1.retry_counts = ");
        writer.write("\naccount.1.user_name = " + data[6]);
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.write("\n");

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

the program is to take a csv and create .cfg files we use for phones with preset information it works in the editor if i run it in netbeans it will do the job and work correctly but as soon as i build it and try to use the .jar executable it will not work.  I need help am I missing something? or is this netbeans not working?

Comment: "It will not work" is not diagnostic. What happens? What doesn't happen? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: My initial guess is a ```FileNotFoundException```. OP, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Netbeans builds the project into the .jar without saying build fail when I try to use the .jar executable created it will not take the file i have called Book1 and build another file called xx.cfg the xx is because it name is based on a variable in the csv the project when told to run in netbeans where you press the the green run button does its job in the folder that the.jar lives in is labled as target.

Comment: in there is where a folder called phones is and the books1.csv is the project in netbeans will run and make the cfg correctly.  But when running the .jar that netbeans makes when told to build which is located in the target folder as well it just wont make the cfg or do anything.  nothing is made and nothing changes.   essentially i jsut want to make this program work where the folder the .jar is in is the place i have the csv and the folder phones it is suppose to populate with cfgs.

Comment: am i jsut dumb and its lookign for a folder that does not exist to it or is it something else.  The program should as the built file take the books.csv and take data from it then build a file that is .cfg based on that data. this works when i run it in netbeans ie the debug play button/green play button.  But it will not do the job when i run the built program.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with Gradle i needed to use the files in the distributions folder then use the windows batch folder it made to run the program